# Multivariate analysis, how to test whether a parameter is different in the two equations?

Tags: r, statistics, multivariate-testing

Let's say I have this multivariate model that is trying to predict number of surgery procedures and number of visits according to number of vets, nurses, diagnostics tests performed and animal's beds:

```
mod <- lm(cbind(surgery,visit) ~ vet+ nurse+ test+ beds, d)
```

How do you test whether the parameter for vet is different in the two equations (one with outcome surgery and the other with outcome visit)?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [summary.manova](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/summary.manova) (called by `summary(manova(fit))`). *Example:*

```
fit <- lm(cbind(mpg, am) ~ hp, mtcars)
summary(manova(fit))
#           Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
# hp         1 0.67967   30.766      2     29 6.778e-08 ***
# Residuals 30                                             
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

In this case Pillai's trace of `hp` yields p < .001, thus we reject the null that the difference of `hp` of both equations is not significant.

Comment: Thanks jay.sf. But if I type Anova(fit, type="II") and summary(manova(fit)) I get Pillai's trace in both cases but with different results. I am not sure of the null hypothesis I am testing in the two cases, could you help me understand?

Comment: You're using `Anova` of the `car` package, read help page section "Details" that elaborates on different types: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-7/topics/Anova